# how to create a excel file in azure function App by using timer trigger

Tags: excel, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-storage-account

I created a method in my azure function app  which gets the static data from a class and stores it to a excel file I am storing the  excel file in a storage account. when I run the method a empty Excel file is created in storage account

1. How to Create a Excel file in Azure function-app
2. How to store a data in Excel file

   ```
   [FunctionName("Function1")]
   public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, [Blob("name/empchange.csv", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream myblob, [Blob("name/TestNewExcel.xlsx", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] TextWriter outputblob)
   {
       log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

       try
       {
           // Read CSV File
           ReadCsvFile(myblob);
           // create Excel File
           CreateExcel(outputblob);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(ex);
       }
   }
   ```

**Excel method:**

```
  static void CreateExcel(TextWriter outputblob)
    {
        data clsdata = new data();
        DataTable table = clsdata.Getdata();

        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(outputblob.ToString(), SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookPart.Workbook = new  Workbook();

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new SheetData();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

            Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet1" };

            sheets.Append(sheet);

            Row headerRow = new Row();

            List<String> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                Row newRow = new Row();
                foreach (String col in columns)
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }
```

my Azure function Bindings:

```
    {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "name/empchange.csv",
      "direction": "in",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"

    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "name/ExcelFile.xlsx",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"

    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: Can this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33cfede9-0c20-488b-a614-bae1f915c291/function-convert-excel-sheet-into-csv-and-csv-into-excel-sheet help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert csv file to excel file, we can use the package [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus)

For example

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run(
           [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *",RunOnStartup =true)] TimerInfo myTimer,
            [Blob("input/test.csv", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudBlockBlob blob,
            [Blob("test/TestNewExcel.xlsx", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream output,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            string worksheetsName = "TEST";

            bool firstRowIsHeader = false;
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
            format.Delimiter = ',';
            format.EOL = "\r";
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"E:\test.xlsx")))
                {

                    string content = await blob.DownloadTextAsync();
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);
                    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(content, format, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium27, firstRowIsHeader);
                    await package.SaveAsAsync(output).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                

            }
           
           
        }
```

[image]
[image]